# Pimcore / Symfony cannot find extension for ‘ pimcore_customer_management_framework’

Tags: symfony, pimcore

I have a local pimcore 6 install that is working fine. When I copy the code to a remote server I am getting the following error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "pimcore_customer_management_framework" (in /opt/bitnami/apps/pimcore/htdocs/app/config/cmf.yml). Looked for namespace "pimcore_customer_management_framework", found "framework", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "cmf_routing", "presta_sitemap", "scheb_two_factor", "security", "web_profiler", "debug", "pimcore_generator", "pimcore", "pimcore_admin", "admin", "pimcore_ecommerce_framework", "app", "httplug", "hwi_oauth" in /opt/bitnami/apps/pimcore/htdocs/app/config/cmf.yml (which is being imported from "/opt/bitnami/apps/pimcore/htdocs/app/config/config.yml").

I copied composer.lock and composer.json from local to remote and ran composer install which ran successfully. All files look correct and in place so i can not see what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Some entries were missing from `htdocs/var/config/extensions.php`. I manually added those to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to enable pimcore_customer_management_framework from admin->bundles

Or

Install Bundle form this link
https://github.com/pimcore/customer-data-framework/blob/master/doc/02_Installation.md and then enable plugin from admin

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable and install bundle via Tools -> Bundles or via console commands: bin/console pimcore:bundle:enable BundleName; bin/console pimcore:bundle:install BundleName.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn’t get to the admin panel due to this error, though i’ve since fixed this by manually adding to extensions.php. i’ll answer below

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25500214)

Comment: @SRack Yes but someone has declined my flag. Can you please raise one?

Comment: To elaborate, I could not access the admin panel, which is where the Tools > Bundles path is located due to the exception stopping the admin panel url from loading. Therefore, this path was not available to me and as such, not a solution to my problem scenario